# Error with python orm peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I love using python orm peewee, but I getting this error again and again.

"InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type"

The most frustrating thing is that it does not shows always. It appears to act arbitrarily.

The code that causes the error is quite simple and as I said, sometimes works sometimes does not.

```
lista=Tareas.select().where((Tareas.ta_usuario==self.user.id) & (Tareas.done=="True"))
for tarea in lista:
     borrada=tarea.delete_instance()
```

Any clue about what can be causing the error?

The difinition of tareas is simple:

```
class Tareas(SqliteModel):
    task = CharField()
    done = CharField()
    ta_usuario = IntegerField()
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of `Tareas`? Also, does replacing `Tareas.done=="True"` with `Tareas.done==True` help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I put more information in my description of the question.

Comment: Also, I don't see the point in changing Tareas.done=="True" with Tareas.done==True since Tareas.done is a char field.

Answer (score 1):

This is [issue #81](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/81). The problem is that you are modifying the data while consuming the loop.

Try this:

```
lista = Tareas.select().where(
    (Tareas.ta_usuario==self.user.id) & (Tareas.done=="True")
)

lista_de_tareas = [i for i in lista]
for tarea in lista_de_tareas:
     borrada = tarea.delete_instance()
```

See the response to the GitHub issue for other solutions.